# How can I get the latest entries in a join table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.1, MySQL and working with 3 classes: Computer, LifecycleStatus & LifecycleEntry

I want to track the history of a Computer's LifecycleStatus over time so the columns in LifecycleEntry are: computer_id:integer, lifecycle_status_id:integer and changed_at:datetime. A computer can have multiple entries in LifecycleStatus.

I have the following associations set up:

```
Computer
  has_many :lifecycle_entries, :order => "changed_at DESC"
  has_many :lifecycle_statuses, :through => :lifecycle_entries

LifecycleEntry
  belongs_to :computer
  belongs_to :lifecycle_status

LifecycleStatus
  has_many :lifecycle_entries
```

I'd like to see, for a particular LifecycleStatus, which computers are currently (their most recent lifecycle_entries record) assigned to that status.

I've managed to create the correct SQL to retrieve this info, but am not sure how to translate this to a Rails association:

```
SELECT id, le.computer_id, lifecycle_status_id
FROM lifecycle_entries AS le
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT lemax.computer_id, MAX(changed_at) AS latest
    FROM lifecycle_entries AS lemax
    GROUP BY lemax.computer_id
) maxdates
ON le.changed_at = maxdates.latest
AND le.computer_id = maxdates.computer_id
WHERE lifecycle_status_id = 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this would be simpler if you denormalized the 'active' status onto the LifecycleEntry itself, updating it each time a new entry is created. This saves you a GROUP BY / MAX query each time you read.

If you have the status column it would be as simple as LifecycleEntry.active.where(:lifecycle_status_id => 6).computers, where active is a scope on LifecycleEntry.

So do the following:

- Add an `active` boolean field to `LifecycleEntry`
- Add a callback to the `LifecycleEntry` model to set the active entry

Here is the callback:

```
after_save :set_active

private

def set_active
  last_active_entry = self.computer.active_lifecycle_entry

  if last_active_entry.nil?
     update_attributes(:active => true)
  elsif changed_at > last_active_entry.changed_at
     last_active_entry.update_attributes(:active => false)
     update_attributes(:active => true)
  end
end
```

It's important to note that the LifecycleEntry being created may precede the currently active one, so you must only set the new one to active if the changed_at is after. Also, for the first LifecycleEntry created, active is always set.

Comment: I suppose I could also have a lifecycle_status_id column in the Computer model and have an after_create/update callback on LifecycleEntry that updates the column in Computer?

Comment: So you're suggesting adding an active:boolean column to LifecycleEntry and when creating a new entry I set it to true and somehow falsify all other entries for that Computer?

Comment: You will only need to falsify the 'active' status on one entry, you have a handle to it when your update operation begins e.g. lifecycle_entry.computer.active_entry

Comment: I updated your answer with the solution I ended up with, based off your suggestion. Note the part about the current entry not necessarily being the most recent one.

Comment: I changed it to be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Where is `active_lifecycle_entry` defined?

Comment: You'd have to define it as something like has_one :active_lifecycle_entry, :class_name => 'LifecycleEntry', :conditions => ['active = ?', true]

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. Thought I tried to set up a has_one through a has_many and Rails complained...